# Taskqueue callbacks in Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, callback, task-queue

I am implementing a google app engine web service that crops very large images. However, cropping can take well over 30 seconds which is (for some reason) a real problem for app engine. To avoid this I have implemented Taskques. However, once the image has been cropped within a Taskqueue I would like to update the page that made the original request, showing to the user the newly cropped image.

So my question is, is there some sort of Taskqueue callback? or do I just have to keep polling a the server to see if my Taskqueue has been finished?

Comment: we use pubnub for that kind of thing. though the channel api would work as well. http://www.pubnub.com/ just publish to a channel as the last thing you do in your scheduled task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/).

Answer (score 0):

goto the 16:00 mark in this video (although I definitely recommend the first 16 minutes as well): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AM0ZPO7-lcE

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer using django-celery, it is more robust and adapted for handling async task.

It also has end-result, which is not there by default but you can use it by specifying so in the settings. you can use that to get any kind of information you require after the task has been completed. Check [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html)

Comment: Celery isn't compatible with GAE task queues.

Comment: @dragonx couldn't you use webhooks?